# How to specify a range of data when using HighCharts with <table>?

Tags: highcharts

I found [this great tutorial](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-parsed/) on using HighCharts with , very useful but I couldn't find a related API letting me only specify a part of data in the table.

For example, in the case above (I added 2 cols to make it more easy to describe), what should I do if I only want to use HighCharts to display the data in a range (in the red dotted range)

Is there some parameter like `datarange:{[0,0,4,4]}` or even sometimes I only want to take care of some more complicated ranges (in the second image)

[image: High Charts Table source with desired ranges to show]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation:

```
 * table : String|HTMLElement
 * A HTML table or the id of such to be parsed as input data. Related options ara startRow,
 * endRow, startColumn and endColumn to delimit what part of the table is used.
```

You can use startColumn/endColumn but data range is unforutnaltey not supported. You can request your suggestion in userVoice http://highcharts.uservoice.com/ system

http://jsfiddle.net/FYtnj/1/

Answer (score 1):

Short description of how data module works you can find in full version of [that file](http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.src.js).

As you can see you can setup `startColumn/startRow` and `endColumn/endRow`. Something like data range isn't supported.

There is `columns/rows` option, but it works in a different way: http://jsfiddle.net/Y53FZ/