# Nested table yields unexpected columns for a basic column graph using high charts with 'Data defined in a HTML table'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

[This demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed) at high charts' website is a good starter point: I  want a `high charts` column graph that gets its data from an html table.  [The accompanying demo's js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-parsed/) is straight forward.

I was able to get a *simple example* like this to work:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    data: {
      table: 'datatable'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
    },
    yAxis: {
      allowDecimals: false,
      title: {
        text: 'Units'
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
          this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<table id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Neil</th>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bob</th>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Joe</th>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

The issue I am running into is when my application happens to have a table nested inside the table. I want to only grab the data from the outer table and have the output look exactly as it did above with my *simple example*. However, this shows how a nested table messes it up:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    data: {
      table: 'datatable'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
    },
    yAxis: {
      allowDecimals: false,
      title: {
        text: 'Units'
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
          this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<table id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Neil</th>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bob</th>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Joe</th>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>First name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Foo</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Bar</td>
              <td>7</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I specify that I only care about the table data from the outer table?  Using the js fiddle example above: I only want the `name` and the `count`.  I don't want anything within the nested table.

I did notice that [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504651/graphical-representation-of-html-table-data-using-high-charts)  as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181019/how-to-specify-a-range-of-data-when-using-highcharts-with-table) appear very similar, but I had trouble applying it to my question. It appears that I just need to add the ids of `startRow` / `endRow` , or `startColumn` / `endColumn` but all my attempts doing so didn't work.

Comment: Please include the problem code in the question itself, or better still you the StackSnippet button (<> in the editor)

Comment: Further more, not much seems to be happening in the linked fiddles.

Comment: @JonP switched it over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `endRow` for your data set (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#data.endRow) as seen below

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    data: {
      table: 'datatable',
      endRow: $("#datatable>tbody>tr").length - 1 //Set last row
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
    },
    yAxis: {
      allowDecimals: false,
      title: {
        text: 'Units'
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
          this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<table id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Neil</th>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bob</th>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Joe</th>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>First name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Foo</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Bar</td>
              <td>7</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```